# Type is invalid -- expected a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, react-native

I am building a Meteor app with ReactJS and Semantic-UI for react. I have run into a problem when trying to create a form for a new item that appears as a modal. I receive the following error.

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `App`.
```

App.jsx file:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

import { Items } from '../api/items.js';

import { Item } from './Item.jsx';
import { ItemFormModal } from './ItemFormModal.jsx';

// App component - represents the whole app
export class App extends Component {

  renderItems() {
    return this.props.items.map((item) => (
      <Item key={item._id} item={item} />
    ));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <header>
          <h1>Products</h1>

          <ItemFormModal />
        </header>

        <ul className="collection">
          {this.renderItems()}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


App.propTypes = {
  items: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};


// creates container on client side for the collection
export default createContainer(() => {
  return {

    // fetch all the items available
    items: Items.find({}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 } }).fetch(),
  };
}, App);
```

EDIT: I have changed it to reflect the whole ItemFormModal.jsx:

```
import { Items } from '../api/items.js';

import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

// Import all semantic resources
import { Button, Icon, Header, Form, Modal } from 'semantic-ui-react';


export default class ItemFormModal extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            title: "",
            price: 0.00,
            modalOpen: false
        }


        this.handleOpen = this.handleOpen.bind(this);
        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleOpen(event) { this.setState({ modalOpen: true }) }

    handleClose(event) { this.setState({ modalOpen: false }) }

    handleInputChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
        [name]: value
        });
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        let title = this.state.title.trim();
        let price = this.state.price;

        Items.insert({
        title: title,
        price: price,
        recurring: false,
        createdAt: new Date(), // current time
        });

        this.setState({
        title: "",
        price: 0.00
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="new-item">
                <Button onClick={this.handleOpen}>Create</Button>
                <Modal
                    open={this.state.modalOpen}
                    onClose={this.handleClose}
                    size="small"
                    closeIcon="close">
                    <Modal.Header>Create new item</Modal.Header>

                    <Modal.Content>
                        <Form>
                            <Form.Group>
                                <Form.Input name="title" label="Title" placeholder="Title" value={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
                                <Form.Input name="price" label="Price" placeholder="Price" value={this.state.price} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Form>
                    </Modal.Content>
                    <Modal.Actions>
                        <Button className="negative" onClick={this.handleClose}>Cancel</Button>
                        <Button className="positive" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Create</Button>
                    </Modal.Actions>

                </Modal>
            </div>
        )
    }


}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: As the error message said "You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.". Do you export your component?

Comment: @Hackjutsu yes, I have this for my class `export default class ItemFormModal extends React.Component`

Comment: Post your ItemFormModal complete code please

Comment: @Cameron That one sees fine. Can you also post your App.js? I think is complaining in that one.

Comment: @sfratini Alright, not sure if that will help. I have tried everything I can think of though so any help is appreciated!

Comment: @Cameron What happens if you dont run the renderItems() function? Looks weird to me, but can't see why.

Comment: @sfratini It doesn't change anything. If I remove `<ItemFormModal />` however, it removes all problems. I would move to chat but not enough rep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are importing into App.jsx incorrectly. you have this:

```
import { ItemFormModal } from './ItemFormModal.jsx';
```

... which will not work if your export is marked as default. you can either remove "default" from your export, or you can change your import to this:

```
import ItemFormModal from './ItemFormModal.jsx';
```